# Laravel - Не компилируются CSS файлы, которые импортируются во Vue.js компонентах

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

Laravel **8.40.0**, Vue.js **2.6.12**

Ни с того ни с сего перестали компилироваться CSS файлы, которые импортируются в компонентах Vue.js:

```html
<template>...</template>

<script>
import VuePhoneNumberInput from 'vue-phone-number-input';
import 'vue-phone-number-input/dist/vue-phone-number-input.css';

// ...
</script>
```

Пришлось их перенести в `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
  .css('node_modules/vue-phone-number-input/dist/vue-phone-number-input.css', 'public/css/app.css');
```

**В чём может быть проблема?**

Comment: почему путь импорта начинается с vue-phone, а в миксине с node_modules, в этом не может быть ошибки?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев, попробовал изменить путь в компоненте — не помогло; в PhpStorm нормально переходит ...

Comment: мне кажется надо не в компоненте, а в миксине, у вас точно есть такой путь node_modules/vue-phone-number-input и тд?

Comment: @МаксимВоробьев, путь есть,.. фишка в том, что раньше всё работало, а недавно перестало. Пробовал откатиться, но ничего.

Comment: А на что ругается-то? Если началось после обновления, попробуйте создать новый проект и взять из него `package.json`.

Comment: @Eugene, ни на что не ругается. Позже попробую на чистом проекте испытать ...

Comment: @Eugene, развернул чистый проект, всё OK; попробовал на домашнем компе старый вариант и упс ... заработало. Даже не знаю, что за треш ... В ПН ещё на рабочем проверю ...

Comment: @Eugene, и на рабочем компе заработало нормально. Какой-то глюк или я что-то где-то изменил и не увидел ...

Comment: У меня тоже не компилировалось, но с кучей ошибок. Помог "переход на новый package.json". Сейчас проверил и со старым все ок. Видимо, обновление кривоватое было.